# Is It Possible to Create a Metric Chart By Commiters via SonarQube

Tags: svn, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Again a SonarQube question.

Is it possible to have a compiled view of certain metrics (i.e. coding rule violations or complexity charts) via SonarQube? I added the SCM Activity plugin, but all it does is line annotation. I also added the SCM Stats plugin, but it shows purely SCM-related statistics, completely unrelated to other Sonar Metrics.

And one more question - is it possible to augment the output of SCM stats to reflect ALL authors instead of just 10? And is it possible to exclude directories from its scope (as far as I understood, it either ignores the sonar.global.exclusions parameter or I set it incorrectly (I use path relative to the directory where I run sonar-runner) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled view of certain metrics (i.e. coding rule violations or complexity charts)"? Aggregated data per project? Per developer?